# Creating an array of Registry Keys in VBS without using oReg.EnumKey

Tags: vbscript

I use this line of code to fill an array with the registry keys at the end of sPath. It works in every instance except Win7. Works on Win8, Win10 no problem. I have verified the keys exist, so it's not that.

```
ret = oReg.EnumKey( &H80000002, sPath, guidlist)
```

I have tried to read out what the return value of "ret", but it appears to be blank or perhaps NULL? I use 'objLog.WriteLine "this is ret " & ret'. but it only writes out "This is ret"

Is there another way to create the array using VBS?

Comment: Is your program running as administrator? It may not have the permissions it needs.

Comment: It is running as Admin. I think I know what's going on. On Win7 EnumKey is defaulting to the WOW6432 registry. The key I'm looking for is in the 64 bit registry tree. I'm going to search for how you specify which part of the registry you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I had to use to get to the 64 bit registry from a 32 bit app without using EnumKey.

```
objLog.WriteLine "Begin StdRegProv reg read method"
strComputer = "."
Const HKLM = &h80000002
Set objCtx = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemNamedValueSet")
objCtx.Add "__ProviderArchitecture", 64
objCtx.Add "__RequiredArchitecture", TRUE
Set objLocator = CreateObject("Wbemscripting.SWbemLocator")
Set objServices = objLocator.ConnectServer("","root\default","","",,,,objCtx)
Set objStdRegProv = objServices.Get("StdRegProv") 

objLog.WriteLine "About to call EnumKey with ExecMethod"

' Use ExecMethod to call the EnumKey method
Set Inparams = objStdRegProv.Methods_("EnumKey").Inparameters
Inparams.Hdefkey = HKLM
Inparams.Ssubkeyname = sPath
'InParams.aArrayOfGuids = guidlist()
'Inparams.Svaluename = "Logging"
set Outparams = objStdRegProv.ExecMethod_("EnumKey", Inparams,,objCtx)

objLog.WriteLine "Finished creating array of guids"
'read values in array
'For Each guid In Outparams.snames
'   objLog.WriteLine "these are the guids in the array - " & guid 
'Next 

For each guid1 in Outparams.snames

    dim InstallPropertiesPath
    InstallPropertiesPath = sPath & "\" & guid1 & SubPath1
    objLog.WriteLine "The InstallPropertiesPath is " & InstallPropertiesPath

    ' Use ExecMethod to call the GetStringValue method
    Set Inparams = objStdRegProv.Methods_("GetStringValue").Inparameters
    Inparams.Hdefkey = HKLM
    Inparams.Ssubkeyname = InstallPropertiesPath
    Inparams.sValueName = "LocalPackage"
    'InParams.aArrayOfGuids = guidlist()
    'Inparams.Svaluename = "Logging"
    set Outparams = Nothing
    set Outparams = objStdRegProv.ExecMethod_("GetStringValue", Inparams,,objCtx)

    objLog.WriteLine "About to call DetectMSIFeature with this path - " & Outparams.SValue
```

Answer (score 1):

EnumKey is the right way to do it. `guidlist` will contain the output you want, not `ret`.

Comment: I'm only looking at "ret" in the cases where it fails to try and figure out why.